# Does Outlook.com provides any webhook/push-notification support?

Tags: web-services, webhooks, outlook.com

I'm planning to write a web service to automate some task for my Outlook.com email account. I want Outlook.com to send an HTTP request to my endpoint when an email arrives, so that I don't need to poll the server. Does Outlook.com provide such functionality?

Comment: Note: not sure whether this is on topic; if not, please suggest where to ask. I had a look at [Web App SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) but it seems to focus on *non-programming* use of web applications.

Comment: I don't think this is on topic, so I'll put this in comments. Does [Outlook Push Notifications REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations) provide what you need?

Comment: @dmulter Thank you. That seems to be exactly the API I was looking for. Do you know a site in Stack Exchange family suitable for this question? If there is such a site, I can move this question there, and you can get the credit.

Comment: Also that way we can help future Googler.

Comment: Seems no one is flagging it, so I'll move it to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook provides webhooks via what they call push notifications. You'll find details on this API in the [Outlook Push Notifications REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations). The capability exists to receive events for a wide variety of resources, including email messages in Outlook.com.

You might also find some useful capabilities for notification of changes to messages with [Use the Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [Keeping messages and mail folders up to date in apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-organize-messages#keeping-messages-and-mail-folders-up-to-date-in-apps).

Comment: Maybe also mention their latest [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-organize-messages#keeping-messages-and-mail-folders-up-to-date-in-apps)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400945/trigger-an-external-api-call-in-outlook-replying-to-an-email-coming-from-a-speci can you please take a look at this

Answer (score 3):

That API has been deprecated.

You must use: [microsoft graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)