# Trigger an external API call in Outlook replying to an email coming from a specific email-id

Tags: java, email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to trigger an external API when i reply to an email coming from a specific sender. To describe the use case , we have an internal platform where people ask specific questions and experts answer them similar to stack overflow.

We want to enable a outlook feature for experts answering questions which would enable the expert to reply to an email notification (coming from the platform) and when he hits send the action would be to call the POST end point for the platform which create a new reply on the original post.

I have looked at Microsoft flow and EWS API but i could not find exactly what I was looking for. I can create custom connectors which would trigger an action when a new email comes in the inbox. But , there was no flow which would trigger an action when you reply to a specific email.

I am looking for some help on what can be done and which APIs/tools can be used to achieve what we are looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the "[on send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins?view=office-js)" capability for Outlook web add-ins, but you are limited to supporting only Outlook Online as it doesn't currently support Outlook for Windows and Mac (and you can't publish the add-in to the Office Store).

The best choice would be to develop a COM add-in where you will have full control over the reply and send events, and the opportunity to cancel or delay those events while you make your web requests.

An outside option is to use [Graph delta queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0) to look for new items in the user's Sent Items folder to detect these send operations.  There are similar capabilities in EWS with [notification subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange) and [transport agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/transport-agents/creating-transport-agents-for-exchange-2013).

Comment: Thanks for the help , would look into the options.

Answer (score 1):

In our case what worked best was using Graph Delta Queries. Since the "on send" capability was limited and outlook web add-in was restricted for our corp outlook.

The solution that worked for us was setting up a separate email address for monitoring all the replies that would go out to our API. Then using graph delta queries we would get the latest emails since the inbox was last synced. The response from the query would be processed and after body is extracted POSTing it to our API with the body as the request body

Comment: Are you running your query manually or automated way? how do you get real time details about emails?