# firebase function triggered on email received

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to trigger a firebase function or create an item in Firestore when an email is received on Gmail or Outlook.

I'm trying to recreate on of ServiceNow's features where in if the helpdesk email address has received an email, it will automatically create a ticket (to firestore) out of it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here is one possible solution for Gmail (untested):

According to the [Gmail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push):

> The Gmail API provides server push notifications that let you watch
> for changes to Gmail mailboxes... Whenever a mailbox changes, the Gmail
> API notifies your backend server application.
>
> ...
>
> The Gmail API uses the [Cloud Pub/Sub API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) to deliver push notifications.

Since you can trigger a Cloud Function [whenever a new Pub/Sub message is sent to a specific topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) you can do as follows:

1. [Set up a Cloud Pub/Sub client](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries).
2. Using your Cloud Pub/Sub client, [create the topic](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#create) that the Gmail API should send notifications to.
3. Configure the Gmail account(s) to [send notifications for mailbox updates](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#getting_gmail_mailbox_updates)
4. [Write a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events?authuser=0#trigger_a_pubsub_function) that is triggered whenever a new Pub/Sub message is sent to this topic and execute the desired Business Logic (e.g. write to Firestore)

---

For Outlook, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56464820/3371862) indicates that it should be possible to call an API when a new mail is received. You could either call an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0) or directly the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest).

Comment: so how can be done using outlook, where should be configured?