# How to automatically update data from outlook to sql using c#, When someone rejects my meeting request it should be updated to my database

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, outlook, active-directory

When someone accepts or rejects my meeting request in outlook. It should be updated automaticaaly to my database as updated or rejected. should be done in c#.

I am trying to use active directory but its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Does Outlook.com provides any webhook/push-notification support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768906/does-outlook-com-provides-any-webhook-push-notification-support)

Comment: Using which API? Outlook Object Model? EWS? Graph? Is your code in a Windows service? Outlook COM addin?

Comment: Do you develop an ASP.NET application?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev yes bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be informed when something changes within an outlook calender you must be actively informed by Microsoft about this change. This can be accomplished by registering a webhook. This means you register a URL via Graph that should be called when a change happens and this URL must be public available.

This theme is quite complex, but if you want to walk that path, you should take a look at [the documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Unfortunately it isn't easy to provide a *simple code sample* that demonstrates the usage. You have to setup a web server (maybe ASP.core) that is public avaialable. This one needs a self-defined route that can by called anonymously. Then you have to follow [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?tabs=http#managing-subscriptions) to let Microsoft call your endpoint when something changed.

The *hardest problems* I had, when setting it up, was that Microsoft sends for subscription validation plain text, which is not supported by default in ASP.core. To add a `TextPlainInputFormatter` [I took this implemenation](https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2020/02/29/asp-net-core-how-to-make-a-controller-endpoint-that-accepts-text-plain/). And in case of subscription validation the ASP model validation must be skipped, cause the body is empty.

Also be aware, while this endpoint is public available and doesn't support any *normal* authentication (like Bearer token or basic) you can still validate that this is a valid request, cause on subscription you define a `clientState`. This can be any random string (we chose `Guid.NewGuid()`). If you store it *on your site* you can compare any incoming request against this secret value for validation.

Comment: bro can you share a sample code if possible

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I added some more hints in my answer.